# How to implement operator*= for big integers without instantiating new vector?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, biginteger

I'm trying to implement a class for working with big integers (e.g. `> 2^64`, which are given by their string representation) in C++.

I use `2^32` as the **base** of the number system, that is, I have a vector that stores digits as integers from `0` to `2^32-1` (`uint32_t` is used for this). I would like to implement the `operator*` and the `operator*=`, in my case the `operator*` via the `operator*=`, while I would like to avoid  instantiating new vector (e.g. `result`) in the implementation of the `operator*=`. On the Internet, I could only find implementations of the `operator*=` via the `operator*` (as [this](https://github.com/panks/BigInteger/blob/master/BigInteger.cpp) one) or just implementations of the `operator*` for two big integers, such as [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/) one. How can I do that?

Below is my current implementation of the `operator*=`:

```cpp
// BASE = 1 << 32
// num: std::vector<uint32_t> num;
bignum& operator*=(const bignum &bn) {
    std::vector<uint32_t> result(size() + bn.size() + 1, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
        uint64_t carry = 0;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < bn.size(); ++j) {
            // static_cast is used to avoid overflow
            uint64_t tmp = static_cast<uint64_t>(num[i]) * bn.num[j] + result[i + j] + carry;
            result[i + j] = tmp % BASE;
            carry = tmp / BASE;
        }

        size_t index = bn.size();
        while (carry > 0) {
           uint64_t tmp = carry + result[i + index];
           result[i + index] = tmp;
           carry = tmp / BASE;
           ++index;
        }
    }

    num = result;

    return *this;
}
```

I will be glad to receive any advice. Have a nice day!

Comment: fwiw, implementing the compound operator in terms of the "normal" operator is not good. Typically it is done the other way around. If the operation cannot be done in place then imho better do not provide the compound operator

Comment: what are the elements of `num` ? digits?

Comment: In my case no, but if `BASE` was 10, then `num`, for example for 54 would store digits or in other words `{4, 5}`.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter while speaking about `operator*=`, isn't it?

Comment: of course it matters what you want to multiply, unless you assume the answer is already obvious ;)

Comment: @MuhammadjonHakimov *while I would like to avoid copying* -- Is this a premature optimization on your part?  Have you measured if copying really is expensive?  What exactly are the members of the `bignum` class?

Comment: @idclev463035818, for `145634049368338284`, which binary representation is `1000000101011001010110010101110011110011010010111101101100`, `num` would store last 32 bits and other bits as it's members (`10000001010110010101100101` and `01110011110011010010111101101100`, or in other words `33908069` and `1942826860`, which will be stored as `{1942826860, 33908069}`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, No I didn't really measured. `bignum` has only one private member `num`, which is a vector and constructors from `uint32_t` and `std::string`, implementations of some operators, such as `operator+, operator*, operator+=, operator*=, operator=` and others.

Comment: `num = result` --  If `num` is a vector, then the compiler may already simply do a `std::move`, and no copy is done.  Or you could explicitly do a `num = std::move(result);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah that makes sense, but I want to get rid of `result` too, ideally.

Comment: you cannot do it without additional memory. Try with pen and paper. If you find a solution I'll be glad to be proven wrong ;)

Comment: @MuhammadjonHakimov Also, you should really try to optimize the possible combination of values that could be multiplied.  For example, what if `bignum` is 1?  Why do anything?  What if `bignum` is 0?  Also, what if `bignum` is not really that big?  You could get away with multiplying two "regular" numbers and just creating a `bignum` from the result.  There are a lot of better optimizations you could do, rather than trying to beat the compiler at the optimization game by avoiding copies.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to implement the operator `*=` at first as you already did. But you should optimize the code to let it reuse the container `num` of `this` to avoid allocation of new memory. Then implementing operator `*` (that does not change its arguments) would be very simple:

```cpp
bignum operator*(bignum left, const bignum &right) const {
    return left *= right;
}
```

Such an approach has 2 advantages:

- There is no copy-paste inside `*` and `*=` operators.
- There is no need to copy the left argument and allocate memory for it if you use `*=`.